# Оплата с помощью ЮКасса в Django

Tags: python, django

Начал делать оплату в проекте django. Делаю по до [документации](https://yookassa.ru/developers/payment-acceptance/getting-started/quick-start). Создал платеж, а ответ получать то как? Оплата работает, все отлично, после этого он меня перенаправляет обратно на мой сайт. Это тестовые платежи.

```py
class Confirmation(DataMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'profiles/confirmation.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Configuration.account_id = ''  # тут есть данные
        Configuration.secret_key = ''

        price = self.get_context_data().get('price')

        payment = Payment.create({
            "amount": {
                "value": f"{price}.00",
                "currency": "RUB"
            },
            "confirmation": {
                "type": "redirect",
                "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmation"
            },
            "capture": True,
            "description": "Заказ №1"
        }, uuid.uuid4())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(payment.confirmation.confirmation_url)
```

Comment: Так по вашей же ссылке всё написано: «Чтобы узнать статус платежа, подпишитесь на уведомления от ЮKassa» и «Также вы можете следить за статусом, запрашивая информацию о платеже»

Comment: Они у меня подключены. Я подумал, я может это потому у меня не `https://127.0.0.1:8000/`, а `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. Не знаете ли вы как можно это поменять?

Comment: Ну как бы 127.0.0.1 это локальный адрес и ЮКасса никак не сможет подключиться к вашему локальному адресу. Приобретайте внешний IP-адрес, покупайте домен и подключайте HTTPS-сертификат. Если вы по каким-то причинам не можете или не хотите это делать, то для вас остаётся единственный вариант самостоятельно запрашивать информацию о платеже (опять же по вашей ссылке всё написано)

Answer (score 1):

Для задачи тестирования можно воспользоваться сервисом [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Это бывает удобнее, даже если хостинг уже есть.
Данный сервис организует "туннель" к вашему localhost и выдаст вам временные https и http адреса вашего сайта для доступа извне.

Таким образом можно настроить/проверить функцию webhook-уведомлений, не прибегая к размещению проекта на хостинге.

Быстро, бесплатно, только регистрация.

И да, поскольку у вас Django, вероятна ситуация "[Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail)".
Поможет прописание строки в settings.py:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']
```